# CloudML: Check failed: size >= 0

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-ml

I came across a strange error happening when I try to train my model using Google CloudML. It doesn't happen when I train the model locally.

```
Check failed: size >= 0 (-1 vs. 0)
```

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45423134/distributed-tensorflow-check-failed-size-0) the problem was solved by changing batch size, which I tried and it didn't help. Any ideas? I am using TF 1.9.0

Comment: Is there any more information in the logs? Like a stack trace?

Comment: @rhaertel80 Nope, and that's the problem.

Comment: Appears that you have a typo in the path to the training or evaluation data, so no files are matching and so you are getting zero records

Comment: @Lak to test your idea I removed all training and evaluation data and ran the job - it ran and no errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem. One of my training parameters was set to -1 when training was done in cloud. I had to look through all of them because there was no stack trace.